# Foreach cast skip?

Tags: c#, foreach, casting

I have a list of some `List<Building> playersBuildings` containing objects all deriving from `Bulilding` class and I came across something that is quite unintuitive to me.

The following code:

```
foreach (Factory f in playersBuildings) {
    f.Update (deltaTime);
}
```

tries to cast every element of `playersBuildings` to `Factory` and yields InvalidCastException error. While it has some sense, while writing the code I hoped that foreach will just omit elements that does not match specified type.

My first thought of solution was this:

```
foreach (Building f in playersBuildings) {
    if ((f is Factory) == false)
        continue;
    (f as Factory).Update (deltaTime);
}
```

but I don't like having to use `as` keyword. Need to type in additional +10 characters every time I want to do something with my `f` under it's iteration is frustrating.

Is there any more elegant way to skip elements not matching the right type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest [OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) *Linq* method to filter out all `Factory` instances:

```
foreach (Factory f in playersBuildings.OfType<Factory>()) {
  f.Update(deltaTime);
}
```

*Non-Linq* solution can be implemented with `?.` operator:

```
foreach (Building b in playersBuildings) {
  (b as Factory)?.Update(deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that all `OfType` does under the hood is an `is` test followed by a cast. That doesnt change the validity of this answer (it's what I would do), just pointing out to the OP he pretty much was on the right track anyways, just that the solution becomes hidden. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/58e46ed059174950.html

Answer (score 0):

As you already have to type `is` we can replace that by `as`:

```
var q = f as Factory;
if(q != null)    
    f.Update(deltaTime);
```

This is a bit shorter then your double check (`is` and `as`)